Remove noise from signal
I use a RTL-SDR dongle to pick up radio signal and the software gqrx to process it. I can hear the signal just fine but there's a bit of background noise. I don't know where it comes from and what the first step of debugging could be. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.
I'm picking up a broadcast wideband FM signal (88.4 MHz) from a radio station 2 km away from my place. I'm using Kubuntu 24.04. I'm not sure how to check for hardware problems.
Here are the settings of the software:

Receiver options

Filter width: Narrow
Filter shape: Normal
Mode: WFM(Mono)
AGC: Fast
Squelch: -150 dB


FFT Settings

FFT size: 8192
Rate: 100 fps
WF Span: Auto
Window: Rectangular
FFT size: 8192



Signal spectrum

Input controls


Is the noise from within the receiver (DSP glitch, hardware problem, etc.) or outside the receiver? Does the noise go away when you remove the antenna?

Hi Jayjay, @RyujiAB1WX makes very good points (as usual!). The first steps to debugging anything is really being clear about your expectations as well – radio reception is a noisy thing, inherently. I'd agree, if you, say, are receiving the FM broadcast station in your own town, then I'd expect "clear" sound, but if you're trying to detect some AM station from thousands of km away – that's not the case! You sadly haven't told us much what you're receiving (broadcast wideband FM? narrowband FM? AM double side band? AM single side band?

I think a screenshot (taken with the screenshot tool of your operating system), which you could add to your question by editing it would help us very much assess your situation :)

Hi @Marcus Müller, thank you very much for your comments. I have updated the post to make my issue clearer. Please let me know if more details are required :)

@jayjay really, that screenshot would help a lot. From your numbers alone we can't guess the noise floor or shape.

@MarcusMüller i added the screenshot but the radio station is not transmitting at the moment. Should I do another one when there is transmission?

I mean, it won't hurt! but this already helps a lot! For example, we see that there seem to be some artifacts left and right of your center frequency that seem to be symmertrical! This is a rather typical artifact of interference that drives your receiver a bit hard, without you actually being tuned to that frequency. Can you check what happens when you tune to 88.6 MHz (instead of 88.4 MHz)? Do they move as well in frequency, or due they stay put that ~0.5 MHz above and below the center frequency?

Please also enable Input controls, and add a screenshot of that and Receiver Options. I am very familiar with gqrx 2.17.3, and that would help a lot. I'll be free in a few hours and will try and draft an answer then.

In the meantime, place your mouse cursor under the -150 and reduce your gain to about -60 with the mouse wheel.

So you took the screen shot when your local (2km) station at 88.4 MHz was not transmitting, right? So why do we see a spectral peak at 88.4MHz? Is there another FM broadcast or some other transmitter at that frequency, or any other device making spurious emission at that frequency? That signal looks like having a decent signal strength, so it could be interfering with your local station. FM modulation has a property called capture effect, where the strongest signal suppresses the weak, but that may still leave some residual noise. Maybe use a directional antenna if possible.

However, I have a local FM station WERS transmitter at about 1km distance from here, and I can see their antenna from my windows. Their signal is pretty strong, and it's easy to make a "crystal radio" with a very crude ratio detector circuit tuned at their frequency. I can't think of any distant FM station or local noise source interfering with that station.

@RyujiAB1WX Sorry I got confused myself. There was transmission from the radio station in the spectrum screenshot.

Ok then my very first question needs to be tested. What happens when you remove the antenna? What happens when you use different antennas? Does the noise change or no.

I don't think you understand what I asked. In the View menu (Alt-V), check all the options (except maybe Full screen). Then the Input controls tab will appear. I still need a screenshot of that.

What you have marked as Input controls is Configure I/O devices, and  is not what I need. :-)
